# Gitlab CE Omnibus keep getting 503 (from GitLab)

Tags: git, apache, proxy, gitlab

I keep getting a 503 Error from Gitlab saying, Gitlab is not responding.

First of all, I installed Gitlab CE Omnibus. I did my Apache configuration so I can access my git using 'https://git.example.com' (I use let's encrypt for the ssl certificates and it works - at least when I do call a simple html-file).

Server: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Apache2.

Well, at first my apache config was not okay and I got 503 Errors from Apache but these errors are solved. Now I keep getting 503 Errors from GitLab. (Yes, there's a difference between apache-503 and gitlab-503 page ;) )

When I take a look in my errorlogs, I can see these lines (for each access):

```
[Sun Jul 23 17:23:02.533490 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 1502:tid 140690612762368] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8181 (*) failed
[Sun Jul 23 17:23:02.533536 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 1502:tid 140690612762368] [client 141.70.82.221:59855] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

I didn't change anything and to be honest, I don't even know why I need to use port 8181.

My .conf for apache is from [web-server/apache](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/web-server/apache) (I changed it according to my needs and as I already said, apache should work now...)